# How does Cloudflare differentiate a request from chrome and from postman?

Tags: http, postman, cloudflare

I can open a Cloudflare protected site in Chrome without problems. In the first GET request, I can see in devtools the complete response being returned with a 200 status.

But if I copy this first request as cURL in devtools, import into Postman and execute it, I will get a response containing claudflare's captcha and a 403 status.

I'd just like to understand - how does Cloudflare knows the postman request doesn't come from a browser? Even with the same IP, the same country, the same user-agent, and all headers.

Comment: Trade secret. Cloudflare doesn't reveal how this is done because if it did, bot authors might have an easier time working around it. If the site is your site, you can disable the protections or create an exception for your particular bot in the Cloudflare dashboard.

Comment: @KentonVarda I actually want to understand so I can try to implement myself such protection for my site. How's that possible? Which HTTP request info might be used for this? I'm guessing I could implement something similar

Comment: @KentonVarda We are not talking about a hidden treasure anywhere in the world! We are talking about technology, and in any case, nothing outside of it has been implemented. So it must be possible to understand it and implement it. That's my question too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71529199/1407491

Comment: I am not sure how cloudflare does it but maybe you can find out in https://github.com/lwthiker/curl-impersonate/tree/v0.5.4

Answer (score 0):

The information is available in the User-agent header of the request.
You can open the command line in Postman and expand request headers to see it.
You can use a Pre-request script to override it and see if that helps: Here is a link to help you on that:
[Postman - Override User-Agent for each request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71938214/postman-override-user-agent-for-each-request)